# `onBlur` is not triggered in 'Jodit` wyswig editor code editor mode, `useCallback` is not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jodit

I have made a codesandbox example with my case and need help making it work.
Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jdit-react-playground-zxwg0) to the example.

Repro steps:

1. Type something on the jodit editor
2. Mouse click on the outside of the editor and you will see the log that says `onBlur` is triggered.
3. Switch to code edit mode using `</>` icon on the top-left.
4. Modify something on the html.
5. Mouse click on outside of the editor and you will NOT see any additional log.

My initial goal is to confirm this mechanism is by design or a bug and I tried to ask to the
community before opening a ticket on the github repository.

You may also have noticed that the logging system is not working properly in my example.

I tried to stack all the logs - `onChange`, `onBlur` but it is showing only the last log. It works fine when I click on the `Add` button. Maybe there is something wrong with react hook usage.

Can someone please help me with the above issues?

1. `onBlur` is not triggered on code edit mode in the `Jodit` editor. Is it by design or a bug?
2. Why do I see only the latest log instead of the stacked logs?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `onBlur` is not called because inside `jodit` a separate `textarea` is used to display the code, this is either a bug in `jodit-react` or in `jodit` itself
2. Inside `jodit-react` callbacks for `textarea` are added inside `useEffect` which is called only when the `config` is changed.
   For the correct display of the logs you need to fix the way of saving the logs to the state

```
const appendLog = useCallback(
  (message) => {
    setLogs(oldLogs => [...oldLogs, message]);
  },
  []
);
```